# Polymer Core Animated Pages setting inside elements height to 0

Tags: polymer

I'm quite new to Polymer (and also to web programming) and I'm having troubles with core-animated-pages.

I've got a set of custom elements inside a div, which were being displayed just fine using % for height and width.
Then I tried wrapping all that into a core-animated-page and - if I don't set an specific height - it collapses height to 0px. Width works just fine as always.

Here is part of my CSS:

```
#tiles-container
    {
        padding-left: 1%;
        height: 85%;
        width: 98%;
        border: 2px;
        border-color: Black;
    }
main-menu-item
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        margin: 1%;
    }
@media (min-height:500px)
    {
        main-menu-item
        {
            height: 30%;
        }
    }
@media (max-height:600px)
    {
        main-menu-item
        {
            height: 135px;
        }
    }
```

Where main-menu-item is my own component. When screen height is less than 600px it works just fine, but not with higher screens.
Here is part of my HTML:

```
<core-toolbar>
    ...
</core-toolbar>
<div class="container" style="overflow-y: auto;" flex>
    <core-animated-pages flex id="pages" selected="0" on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{transitionend}}"
        transitions="cross-fade-all hero-transition">
        <section>
            <div id="tiles-container" class="tiles-container" layout wrap horizontal around-justified center relative>
                //mi custom elements just thrown in here
                ...
            </div>
        </section>
    </core-animated-pages>
</div>
<core-toolbar>
     ...
</core-toolbar>
```

It'd be great if someone would give me a solution other than giving my custom elements an static height.
Thanks for reading and sorry for my english! ^^u

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, I'm trying to embed multiple custom elements containing core-animated-pages and they end up calculating height: 0 and overlapping each other.

In all the custom elements I've found that use core-animated-pages, the element is always at the end of the page (I believe everyone places the content at the bottom of the page to avoid this height issue).

My solution for now is to set the height explicitly as you have done.

Comment: Setting an explicit height doesn't make sense to me, since the whole point - for me - of using polymer is to make easier for me to have control's size adjust nicely. I'd rather go without animations than lose the height percentage. Thanks for answering anyway :)

Comment: I finally changed core-animated-pages for core-pages (fancy style as in the official Polymer demo) and I managed to get a nice animated transition plus maintaining height percentage benefits. I don't know if that's useful for you but could be.

Comment: I tried switching to core-pages, saw the same behavior. Must be something else messing with the height in my case. I'm living with it for now.

Comment: I've noticed that using animated-pages, elements in them will lose their height no matter what. With core-pages elements themselves do not change height, but if you put them inside a div they react exactly the same way as with animated-pages. If I find out a reason for this I'll let you know, right now I just don't understand.